# Angular2 Formly and multiple page forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-formly

I am going to use the Angular2 Formly (ngx-formly) library to allow for JSON-defined forms. Can anyone offer advice on how to break up a form into multiple pages based on the JSON configuration one develops?  I expect to have to structure my JSON to go to multiple components but wondered if anyone has advice on how to properly do it based on their experience?  Thanks in advance.

Example:

**Page 1**

Demographics

-- FirstName

-- LastName

-- SSN

-- DOB

**Page 2**

Insurance Info

-- Company

-- Policy

-- (variable number of fields that should go to a third page possibly)

Answer (score 0):

the doc examples include a multi-step demo using material, see https://formly.dev/examples/advanced/multi-step-form